# Insert long code into PHP table td

Tags: php, html-table

I'm creating something similar to the "wall" on Facebook where there are comments followed by textareas to insert more comments.  I have done this through a PHP generated table taking variables from a mysql database:

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';
$get=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE $x='comments' ORDER by rank DESC");
echo '<table>';

while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($get)){
 echo '<tr>';
echo "<td>//DIV IN HERE!</td>";
 echo '</tr>';
echo '<tr>';
echo "<td><form> ... </form></td>";
echo '</tr>';

}

echo '</table>';
?>
```

However, I have a div setup that I would like to place in the cell of the table.  This div has sub Divs and echos information and is generally messy.  I have tried to include this div into the td but I'm getting lots of errors probably because I had to change all the " to '.  Is there a better way I should be approaching this? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Would you be able to show what your DB table looks like?

Also, I would recommend not using tables in HTML for dividing content (such as posts/comments). What would be better is using a div. So for instance, you'll want something like

```
<div class="postContainer">
    <div class="postMsg">Hi there</div>
    <div class="postMsgComment">Hi to you, too!</div>
    <div class="postMsgComment">I want to join the fun!!!</div>
</div>
```

From here, your SQL table would have a foreign key in your comments table, pointing to which "wall" post it was intended for.

tbl.Post

| PostId | UserId | Date | Message | (..)

tbl.Comment

| CommentId | PostId | UserId | Date | Message | (..)

Comment: thanks but could you expand on this a little more. im kinda new, but your idea sounds like the right path.  what is this foreign key?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like in this case it'd be much easier to jump out of PHP into HTML markup — this way you won't need to worry about escaping `'` or `"`.

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';
$get=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE $x='comments' ORDER by rank DESC");
echo '<table>';

while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($get)){
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>
                <?php echo $something; ?>
                <div id="sub-div"></div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><form> ... </form></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
}

echo '</table>';
?>
```

Comment: but the number of cells in the table is variable depending on how many posts there are (each post can be commented on).  I need the <td> to be in the while loop

Comment: It is still inside the while loop

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a good time to use the [HEREDOC string syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)

```
while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($get)){
  echo<<<HTML
  <tr>
    <td>
     <div> {$row['somevalue']} </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><form> ... </form></td>
  </tr>
HTML;
}
```